# custom claims in Azure AD to add windows AD groups

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I would like to know how can I add a windows AD group into a custom claim on Azure AD? I am looking to use AD groups for applications running on a platform that uses role-claims or custom claims to enable applications to have access groups or AD groups separately.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take[the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your source code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can add the custom group claims in a token configuration for your application deployed in Azure AD as follows. Also, since you are adding AD groups, it is considered that those groups are synchronized from on-premises AD through Azure AD Connect to be used as group claims in token configuration.

1. To configure group claims, go to your configured application in Azure AD  enterprise applications, click on the application and select ‘Single Sign On’  User Attributes & Claims  Add a group claim  Use the radio buttons to select the ‘Security groups’ option as below

[image: AAD Group claim]

2. To emit groups using Active Directory attributes synced from Active Directory instead of Azure AD objectIDs select the required format from the drop-down. Only groups synchronized from Active Directory will be included in the claims.
   [image: Group claim source attribute]
3. To configure the group claim as a custom claim role by giving it a custom claim name, select the box ‘Customize the name of the group claim’ as below while also checking the box ‘Emit groups as role claims’ to use the group as a role claim in your application. Please take into consideration that if the option to emit group data as roles is used, only groups will appear in the role claim. Any Application Roles the user is assigned will not appear in the role claim.

[image: Group claim advanced options]

Thus, you can configure AD groups as role claims for an application in Azure AD. Please find the documentation link for reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#add-group-claims-to-tokens-for-saml-applications-using-sso-configuration